# Maven finds imported repositories, but IntelliJ can't resolve their packages

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

The Problem is IntelliJ itself. I copied a Project from another PC to this one, but it does not work.

Main problem is, that Redis and MongoDB won't get find by IntelliJ. Maven has no problems with finding the repos, and the jars are in the .m2 folder too.

But this is what I see:

[image: Missing Import]

[image: Error: Resource nexus-maven-repository-index.properties does not exist]

On the other PC the Project is working fine, so why am I getting here this issue?

I already tried:

- Invalidate Caches
- Reimport
- Autoimport
- clear .m2 folder and reload project.

But nothing seems to work....

EDIT:

This is what my maven project looks like

[image]

Comment: Problems with Proxy or Firewall? If you try to ping the Server you get an answer?

Comment: The servers are all fine. And on my surface, it works like a charm. The issue lies in the configuration of my PCs IntelliJ i guess...

Comment: In IntelliJ, open the view `Maven project`. Then go to the node `Lifecycle` and perform `clean` and `package` . What is the result?

Comment: @JimHawkins I was able to do clean, but not package on this way. This is what my maven project looks like, what does the underlined mean?

Comment: what is the result, when you quit IntelliJ and execute `mvn clean package` from command line in the project folder?

Comment: Exit code 1 and several "error when unzip file"  messages.

Comment: now it's clear that there is a misconfiguration in maven. Maybe in IntelliJ, too. But first we have to solve the issue in your maven configuration.

Comment: Sometimes I encounter this problem due to IDEA using a bundle maven by default, but actually my M2_HOME is point to another maven in my PC, even the repo are in the user_home .m2, you can check this.

Answer (score 0):

If your OS is Windows, open `C:\Users\yourWindowsAccount\.m2\settings.xml` . Check if the section `<proxies>` contains a valid entry, similar to this:

```xml
<proxies>
    <!--
        proxy | Specification for one proxy, to be used in connecting to the
        network. |
    -->
    <proxy>
        <id>optional</id>
        <active>true</active>
        <protocol>http</protocol>
        <username></username>
        <password></password>
        <host>proxyyour.company.com</host>
        <port>8080</port>
        <nonProxyHosts>localhost</nonProxyHosts>
    </proxy>
</proxies>
```

When you delete the complete folder `.m2` (as you've told), you've deleted `settings.xml`, too. So you've to create a new one.

Compare your own `settings.xml` with the file on the other machine, where everything works fine.

To define a proxy in IntelliJ IDEA, go to Menu `File` --> `Settings...` --> `Appeareance & Behaviour` --> `System Settings` --> `HTTP Proxy` and enter the proper configuration:

[image]

Comment: I reinstalled my complete windows, because I thought my windows was the culprit.

Comment: Now i found out that each downloaded jar by maven has only 1kb! They couldnt successfully download the jars!